# Problemas com CORS em aplicação utilizando API com Slim framework e angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, slim, cors

Boa tarde amigos

Estou tendo problemas para resolver um problema

`Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://api.dominio.com.br/exemplo. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' é incompatível com 'http://api.dominio.com.br').`

Criei uma **API** utilizando Slim para "alimentar" minha  aplicação em **AngularJS**.

```
require "Slim/Slim.php";
require "CorsSlim/CorsSlim.php";

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$corsOptions = array("origin" => "*", "allowMethods" => array("POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));

$cors = new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim($corsOptions);

$app->add($cors);
//e aqui vem as rotas
$app->run();
```

Fiz uma busca pelo **StackoverFlow** antes de abrir essa enquete, e entrei em contato para ver se minha hospedagem estava habilitado o CORS. Como e uma hospedagem compartilhada o mesmo e desabilitado. 
Gostaria de uma ajuda pra resolver essa questão, desde já agradeço.

Resposta da **RESTClient**:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Authorization,X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 00:03:56 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cacheable: YES
X-Varnish: 1680708969
access-control-allow-origin: *
magicmarker: 1
```

Comment: https://crossorigin.me/ ;)

Comment: valeu pela resposta rápida... mas essa forma de requisição só aceita GET. Mas agradeço sua colaboração.

Comment: Você chegou a testar? Ele faz uma requisição GET no seu domínio e retorna o que veio.

Comment: testei mas não funcionou pois minha API também tem validação de token ai acho que por isso dificultou também.

Comment: eu encontrei esse site mais não entendi como utilizar http://enable-cors.org/index.html

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema eu resolvi adicionando os headers na requisição: Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ;)

Comment: Assim Laerte o Slim já está fazendo isso para min .. $corsOptions